# min height fill_parent and height wrap_content in ScrollView? (or just the email app compose layout's code)

Tags: android, android-layout

**Question** If I have the following:

```
<ScrollView android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="?" android:orientation="vertical">
        <EditText android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="?" android:hint="Subject" android:id="@+id/subject" />
        <EditText android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="?" android:id="@+id/body" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

How can I get the body (second EditText) to fill the rest of the screen, but still have the scrollview kick in when the contents of the body are too long? Like a `height="wrap_content"` and `minHeight="fill_parent"`

`layout_height="fill_parent"` seems to not do anything if you put them in a scrollview

**A working example of what I want is the email app compose window**

**I tried this** and the EditText elements act like they are wrap_content and no filling is happening. Just scrolling if you type enough

```
<ScrollView android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:orientation="vertical">
        <EditText android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" layout_weight="1" android:hint="Subject" android:id="@+id/subject" />
        <EditText android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" layout_weight="1" android:id="@+id/body" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 92, accepted):

I ran across a link to the [mail app source code](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/Email.git;a=tree;hb=master) in [my accepted answer on another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3885074/make-my-activity-one-of-the-mail-apps-shown-in-the-intent-chooser/3885181#3885181). The answer is simple! Add `android:fillViewport="true"` to the `<ScrollView...>` and add `android:layout_weight="1.0"` to the view you want to take up all the available space. explained in this [blogspot](https://web.archive.org/web/20100818151912/http://www.curious-creature.org/2010/08/15/scrollviews-handy-trick/)

Comment: Just for those who run across this, don't forget that you need to specify weight like I did above.

Comment: Romain Guy explains this technique in a blog post: http://www.curious-creature.org/2010/08/15/scrollviews-handy-trick/

Comment: @MarcoW. how would you make the scrollview let its child as much space as it needs, but let the scrollview have a maximal height? for example: max height is 100dp. if child needs less than that, both child and scrollView have their height to this value (which is less than 100dp). if the child needs 100dp or more, both of them will get the height of 100dp.

Comment: The link to the blog post doesn't work, I read it with [web archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20100818151912/http://www.curious-creature.org/2010/08/15/scrollviews-handy-trick/)

Answer (score 7):

As mentioned above the right way is to use the **android:fillViewport="true"** attribute.

There is an example, where the image will be positioned at the and of scrollView:

```
  <ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">
    <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:fillViewport="true"
      android:orientation="vertical">

      <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <TextView
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="test"/>
      </LinearLayout>


      <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@color/red">
        <ImageView
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:adjustViewBounds="true"
          android:src="@drawable/about_us_image_1_land"
          style="@style/layout_marginTop20"/>
      </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
   </ScrollView>
```

Comment: Instead of fill_parent you should really use match_parent. +1 for the example!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you make the ScrollView being fill_parent and A and B to wrap_content ?
The only thing you want is that your ScrollView fits the screen.

Comment: I also want textarea B to fill the screen. Like a min-height: fill_parent.

Comment: Try with a LinearLayout and layout_weight="1" on each A and B with layout_height="fill_parent" on A and B too

Answer (score 0):

after you call

```
AlertDialog dialog = builder.show();
```

then call

```
fixScrollViewHeight(scrollView);

private void fixScrollViewHeight(ScrollView scrollView)
{
    int screenHeight = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();
    LayoutParams lp = scrollView.getLayoutParams();
    lp.height = screenHeight / 3;
    scrollView.setLayoutParams(lp);
}
```