# Make my activity one of the mail apps shown in the intent chooser

Tags: android, android-intent

When clicking an email address from a browser or contacts app...

Is there any way for my app to show a mail client in the intent list?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but please, don't do this "automatically."  Give the user the choice.  I *hate* apps that change any default behavior(s) I have chosen.

Comment: @Wonko, don't worry, Android only let's the user select the default application, applications themselves can't do that :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can see from the [Mail application's source](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/Email.git;a=blob;f=AndroidManifest.xml;h=a21a23d455b02173094d7f176b7e0e731b96efa4;hb=master#l200), having your application catch the intent is as simple as adding the `intent-filter` to your `AndroidManifest.xml` inside your mail composition `activity` definition.

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" />
    <data android:scheme="mailto" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
</intent-filter>
```

You can see that the `<data>` tag specifies to handle `mailto:` links. The `BROWSABLE` category means it can be launched from the browser.

[K-9 Mail](http://code.google.com/p/k9mail/source/browse/k9mail/trunk/AndroidManifest.xml#217) is similar, except using the `SENDTO` action only with the `DEFAULT` category, and the `VIEW` action only with the `BROWSABLE` category.

Comment: How can the android system know which of my activities is the compose mail activity?

Comment: @GeorgeBailey Updated my answer with examples from both the Mail app and K-9.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks! Also thanks for the link to the mail app source. I should be able to find the compose layout xml to answer my other question

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an `Intent Filter`.  Check out http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html for more information.  You usually declare these in your manifest file.  The intent I believe you're looking for is `Intent.ACTION_SEND`.