# Collapsing and scrolling Views in a LinearLayout View

Tags: android-layout, android-layout-weight

I'm trying to create a very specific behavior in an Android layout containing two Fragments when the soft keyboard opens, as depicted below from left to right.

Fragment A is a form which requires soft keyboard input, and Fragment B is a photographic slideshow, and just serves as visual filler.

[image: Behavior of android layout while opening keyboard]
The blue outline represents the root View. Fragment A is a fixed height, and Fragment B fills the remaining vertical space. As the keyboard opens, Fragment B collapses until its height is 0, at which point fragment A becomes scrollable.

I've tried the following:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <FrameLayout
      android:id="@+id/FragmentB"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="0dp"
      android:layout_weight="1" />
  <ScrollView
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/FragmentA"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
  </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

In this view Fragment B remains at the same height when the soft keyboard opens and instead Fragment A collapses.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
  <LinearLayout
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/FragmentB"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/FragmentA"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
  </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

And in this view Fragment B is constantly collapsed, and a gap remains at the bottom of the view below Fragment A.

**How can I achieve the layout behavior I laid out in the diagram above?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution here:

[Min height fill_parent and height wrap_content in ScrollView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3881975/min-height-fill-parent-and-height-wrap-content-in-scrollview-or-just-the-email)
My resulting code is:

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">  <!-- FillViewport ensures the scrollview doesn't wrap the content -->
  <LinearLayout
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_weight="1"> <!-- Layout weight 1 means the LinearLayout will at least fill the scrollview, or wrap content if too big -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/FragmentB"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/FragmentA"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
  </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```